# modifying asembly code of android aplication with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, reverse-engineering

There is an APK that uses firebase library (malware).
Can I decompile the APK, modify the smali code, and compile it again using method from here https://github.com/dpox/ctfs/blob/master/googlectf2016/IllIntentions.md ? (apktool d, modifying smali code, apktool b (bulding the app), signing the APK).
Will be firebase service in this new APK be working?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: The problem is that the firebase service seems like isn't working in the malware and I wanted to add a debug messages in the beginning of OnTokenRefresh(). (OnTokenRefresh is only one thing with firebase in the malware). I wanted to know whether OnTokenRefresh is executed. When I'll add logging and I won't see this log I won't know if OnTokenRefresh isn't really executed or did I something wrong.

Comment: It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in [Stack Exchange Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).